# How to Convert a string Array to Strut Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, structure

my code is,

```
struct Datas{
   let fName: String
   let lName : Strin
}

let anArray : String = ["name1","name2","name2","name2"]
let datas : [Datas] = [Datas]()
```

How can i store anArray data to datas (only fName)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to take a course or tutorial on swift.

However the answer is here:

```
import Foundation
struct Datas{
    let fName: String
    var lName : String? = nil
}

let anArray : [String] = ["name1","name2","name2","name2"]

let datas = anArray.map { Datas(fName: $0) }
```

Comment: Yes, i'm learning...
i want only fName,  xcode asks for lName too